# All table rows re-render after selection changes

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have table of customers and the selected customer is stored in the `ViewState`. The problem is that all rows re-render when the selection changes which is quite slow. Ideally only the selected row and the row previously selected would re-render, but I did not find out how to achieve this. My structure is identical to the example in the [MobX contact list example](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-contacts-list/):

```
{this.filteredCustomers.map(customer => {
   return (
      <CustomerRow
         key={customer.id}
         customer={customer}                    
         viewState={this.props.store.view}
      />
   )                
})}
```

and

```
const CustomerRow = observer((props: CustomerRowProps) => {
   const isSelected = props.viewState.isCustomerSelected(props.customer)
   const rowClass = isSelected ? 'active' : ''

   return (
     <tr className={rowClass}>
       <td>{props.customer.lastName}</td>
       <td>{props.customer.firstName}</td>
     </tr>
   )
})
```

All rows depend on the value of `ViewState.selectedCustomer` through the `isCustomerSelected` method.

Is there another way to structure this that avoids re-rendering all rows?

Comment: Can you upload `CustomerRow` render as well ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing both components in their entirety, but I recreated an example, and [**it works for me**](http://jsbin.com/qapilekina/edit?js,output).

Comment: @Tholle: the "trick" in your case is that you put the selection information into each row with the `active` flag, so that the row only depends on the object and not on the view state. Is that a general pattern?

Comment: Yeah, it's a common pattern. It is e.g. used in the [**introduction to MobX**](https://youtu.be/K8dr8BMU7-8?t=7m11s) by Weststrate, the creator of MobX. But it was not be the best example by me, since you might not want to add extra fields to the data just for the view.

Comment: have you tried `PureComponent` instead of regular `Component`? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent

Answer (score 4):

You can use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to deside wheather component updates or not.

Comment: No, that's what I am using mobx for. Or are there cases where one has to combine mobx and shouldComponentUpdate?

Comment: If using one of them is not working for you I think you need to combine them.

Comment: It is worth noting that marking a component with @observer will remove the need to implement shouldComponentUpdate in that component, in fact it will give you a warning "Use `shouldComponentUpdate` in an `observer` based component breaks the behavior of `observer` and might lead to unexpected results. Manually implementing `sCU` should not be needed when using mobx-react"

Answer (score 3):

The reason why all the rows are re-rendered is because `props.viewState.isCustomerSelected(props.customer)` has to be re-evaluated for each observer component when the used observable change.

One way to get around this is to use a [**map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) so that every entry will have a potential  `checked` field of their own, so that only the selected and deselected components have to re-render.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qisezukeso/edit?js,output))**

```
class AppState {
  @observable todos = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Do something'
    }, 
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Do something else'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Do a third thing'
    }
  ]

}

var appState = new AppState();

@observer
class Todos extends React.Component {
  checked = observable.map({});

  changeTodo = (todo) => {
    this.checked.clear();
    this.checked.set(todo.id, true);
  };

  render() {
    return <div>
      <ul>
        { this.props.appState.todos.map((todo) =>
          <Todo 
            todo={todo} 
            key={todo.id}
            checked={this.checked}
            onChange={() => this.changeTodo(todo)} />
        ) }
      </ul>
      <DevTools />
    </div>;
  }
}

@observer
class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { todo, checked, onChange } = this.props;
    const isChecked = checked.get(todo.id);
    return <li>
      <input 
        type="checkbox"
        checked={isChecked} 
        onChange={onChange} />
      {todo.title}
    </li>;
  }
}
```